# regex match hh:mm:ss optional hours

Tags: javascript

I have `/^(?:1[0-2]|0[0-9]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$/` pattern which works in PHP but when I tried to use it in Js, it doesn't work. I want to match only two formats with mandatory leading zeros: 00:00:00 or 00:00

Comment: Please tell us what this regex is supposed to be matching.  This also would not match optional seconds in PHP, hence why I am dropping a comment.

Comment: That won't work in PHP either. You need to make the last part optional with `?`

Comment: What's the reason for the non-capturing group at the beginning?

Comment: optional hours I mean. not seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the group containing the hours optional by putting `?` after it, and also put the colon following it into the group.

```js
console.log(/^(?:1[0-2]|0[0-9]:)?[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$/.test("00:00:00"));
console.log(/^(?:1[0-2]|0[0-9]:)?[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$/.test("00:00"));
```

I'll bet you had this in the PHP version, since that seems like the only reason to have the non-capturing group in the first place. You probably just missed it when copying to Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you want optional hours, then just make the hours component of your pattern optional:

```
^(?:(?:1[0-2]|0[0-9]):)?[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$
```

```js
console.log(/^(?:(?:1[0-2]|0[0-9]):)?[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$/.test("10:00:00"));
console.log(/^(?:(?:1[0-2]|0[0-9]):)?[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$/.test("00:00"));
```

Comment: What's the reason for the nested non-capturing group.

Answer (score 0):

To also match 00:00 then i assume the first part with the hours must be made optional.

This regex will also put the hour/minute/second into the capture groups $1 $2 $3.

```
^(?:(1[0-2]|0[0-9])[:])?([0-5][0-9])[:]([0-5][0-9])$
```

**Test snippet:**

```js
const reg = /^(?:(1[0-2]|0[0-9])[:])?([0-5][0-9])[:]([0-5][0-9])$/;

strings = ["00:00:00","00:00","12:01","24:59","59:59","12:59:59",
           "14:15:16","00:60","60:00","0:0:0"]

for (const s of strings) {
   console.log(s+" : "+reg.test(s));
}
```

For a 24 hour notation "00:00:00" till "23:59:59" & "00:00" till "59:59", the pattern below can be used

```
^(?:([01][0-9]|2[0-3])[:])?([0-5][0-9])[:]([0-5][0-9])$
```

Comment: It's the first part that's optional,not the last. And why do you put `:` inside `[]`?

Comment: Oh that's because it uses a non-capturing group. `(:`. And `(:[:]` looks less confusing than `(::`.  But alright, I'll make the first group optional.